# Return last created_at from array with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do the following in mongoDB:

Get latest comment for every user

Below is the model

```
   {
   "userId":"UserA",
   "comments":[
      {
         "text":"abcd",
         "created_at":"2015-10-09T03:34:46.701Z",
         "commentNumber":1
      },
      {
         "text":"abcde",
         "created_at":"2015-10-09T04:34:46.701Z",
         "commentNumber":2
      }
   ]
}
```

My expected output is

```
{ "userId":"UserA" ,  "comments": [{
                      "text":"abcde",
                      "created_at":"2015-10-09T04:34:46.701Z",
                      "commentNumber":2
                      }]
},
{ "userId":"UserB" ,  "comments": [{
                      "text":"ghij",
                      "created_at":"2015-10-10T04:34:46.701Z",
                      "commentNumber":3
                      }]
}
```

I tried to play with something like this but it doesn't do what i needed
`db.users.find({'comments.commentNumber':3},{'comments.$':1})`

Neither if I use the sort on created_at - still returns all the array of the subdocuments

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want the most recent value of "created_at" instead? Is there any reason why this would not always be the last element of the array? Unless you are modifying the `$push` behvavior the last array element is always the most recent addition.

Comment: I suggest you rethink your data model. As you have it now each user can only create a limited number of comments before you exceed the maximum document size. You should store comments in a separate collection unless this is some really tiny application,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the "latest" is always the "last" ( which it should be when appending to arrays ) then you want [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to return the last array element:

```js
db.users.find({},{ "comments": { "$slice": -1 } })
```

If for some reason this is not in that order, then you need to manipulate the array with `.aggregate()`:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },
    { "$sort": { "comments.created_at": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "userId": { "$first": "$userId" },
        "comments": { "$last": "$comments" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "userId": { "$first": "$userId" },
        "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
    }}
])
```

And only needing the second `$group` there to create an array after finding the [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) entry after [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/).